# VBA = Object Required Error

Tags: vba, excel

When executing the function I wrote, I get the following Error

"Object Required"

The Function is as follows:

```
Sub ResizeTable4()
    ResizeTabell234("Tabell4", "Table11", "M", "O", "P") = Object
End Sub 



Function ResizeTabell234(SheetName As String, TableName As String, OuterBoarderOfTable As String, CurrentValue As String, NewValue As String)

    Dim CurrentWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ObjectList As ListObject

    Dim NewResizeRange, CurrentRange As Long

    Set CurrentWorkSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
    Set ObjectList = CurrentWorkSheet.ListObjects(TableName)

    CurrentRange = Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(2, CurrentValue).Value
    NewResizeRange = Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(2, NewValue).Value

    If NewResizeRange > CurrentRange Or NewResizeRange = CurrentRange Then

        ObjectList.Resize CurrentWorkSheet.Range("A1:" & OuterBoarderOfTable & NewResizeRange)

    Else

        ObjectList.Resize CurrentWorkSheet.Range("A1:" & OuterBoarderOfTable & NewResizeRange)

        NewResizeRange = NewResizeRange + 1

        Range("A" & NewResizeRange, OuterBoarderOfTable & CurrentRange).Clear

    End If


End Function
```

Without the * = Object * The function did not even run. I tried

```
Dim object As Object
```

But that did not work. I'm new to VBA and I'm try to learn on my own but cannot figure out why it's not work. Any Ideas?

Comment: Remove the =Object and the parentheses around the arguments.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I tried Dim object As Object, that did not work

Comment: What sort of object is `Object`?  You have your order incorrect as well - a function can return a value, while it appears you're trying to say `MyFunction = ThisObject`.  Your function could create the object and pass it back to a variable to be referenced later in which case you'd use `Set MyObject = MyFunction`, but your function doesn't do that. Anyway.... type of object again?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you Tim! That Worked perfectly